# Some databases are not visible in Database View of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: database, intellij-idea

For some reason some databases are not visible in Database View of IntelliJ IDEA.

I'm using:

- IntelliJ IDEA 122.519
- MySql 5.5 on Linux Centos 6.3

I did fresh install of mysql. There is `test` db as you remember.

I created DB DataSource in IDEA and specified root credentials. Then right-clicked on it and hit "Refresh". It shows me following databases in UI:

- information_schema
- mysql
- performance_schema

But there is no `test` !

Interestingly enough I can see `test` if I go to Data Source Properties dialog and check `Schemas & Tables` tab.

Is it a bug ?

I don't know why it's happening but I have a feeling it has something to do with what user created particular database.

Any ideas how to see everything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create at least one table in this schema.